# Selenium WebDriver can't get elements

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing tests for a web site using Selenium WebDriver. I have looked at element's id & xpath in firebug and firepath. Ids exist but I get an exception. Could you please provide help? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, check if this element is visible when Selenium tries to catch it. If an element is hidden (for example, if you attempt to get menu item which displays only on hover event), Selenium doesn't see it too.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. It has to be hovered over to become visible. What should I use to make clicking this button possible?

Comment: Try to use Actions, place this code before you want to get access to the element

`Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
                        builder.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("<place a parent item of ext-gen55 which is visible>"))).Build().Perform();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HTML Agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to create a HtmlNode of your page, and then query it by XPath to find your element.
The benefit being that you need not be worried about the visibility of the elements to grab them.

Comment: Thanks it is another thing I shall discover